# [[ ]]の意味について

Tags: python

下記のような[[   ]]はどういう意味でしょうか？

```
[[temp_pred]] = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x_data:t, y_target:y_data})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

シーケンスの展開代入です。

```
>>> x, y = 1, 2
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> (x, y) = (1, 2)
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> [x, y] = (1, 2)
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> [x, y] = [1, 2]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> [x, [y]] = [1, [2]]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> [[y]] = [[2]]
>>> y
2
```